Sabre PNR says "Unable to process the stateless transaction. Please retry."
I am currently trying to create pnr using sabre json api. "But I am getting Unable to process the stateless transaction. Please retry."
Converstation-id: 751e1e19-ed8d-4546-b913-96410528c28a
this is my request. I have followed postman collection provided by sabre devs.
{
    "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
      "version": "2.5.0",
      "targetCity": "****",
      "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
        "AgencyInfo": {
          "Address": {
            "AddressLine": "SABRE TRAVEL",
            "CityName": "SOUTHLAKE",
            "CountryCode": "US",
            "PostalCode": "76092",
            "StateCountyProv": {
              "StateCode": "TX"
            },
            "StreetNmbr": "3150 SABRE DRIVE",
            "VendorPrefs": {
              "Airline": {
                "Hosted": true
              }
            }
          },
          "Ticketing": {
            "TicketType": "7TAW"
          }
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
          "ContactNumbers": {
            "ContactNumber": [
              {
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "Phone": "817-555-1212",
                "PhoneUseType": "H"
              }
            ]
          },
          "PersonName": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "NameReference": "ABC123",
              "PassengerType": "ADT",
              "GivenName": "ABC",
              "Surname": "DEF"
            }
        
          ]
        }
      },
      "AirBook": {
        "OriginDestinationInformation": {
          "FlightSegment": [
            {
              "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-10-18T04:20:00+04:00",
              "DepartureDateTime": "2024-10-18T01:15:00+05:45",
              "FlightNumber": "2154",
              "NumberInParty": "1",
              "ResBookDesigCode": "K",
              "Status": "NN",
              "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
              },
              "MarketingAirline": {
                "Code": "EK",
                "FlightNumber": "2154"
              },
              "MarriageGrp": "O",
              "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "KTM"
              }
            },
            {
              "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-10-19T07:05:00+11:00",
              "DepartureDateTime": "2024-10-18T10:15:00+04:00",
              "FlightNumber": "412",
              "NumberInParty": "1",
              "ResBookDesigCode": "K",
              "Status": "NN",
              "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "SYD"
              },
              "MarketingAirline": {
                "Code": "AA",
                "FlightNumber": "412"
              },
              "MarriageGrp": "I",
              "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "AirPrice": [
        {
          "PriceRequestInformation": {
            "Retain": true,
            "OptionalQualifiers": {
              "FOP_Qualifiers": {
                "BasicFOP": {
                  "Type": "CK"
                }
              },
              "PricingQualifiers": {
                "PassengerType": [
                  {
                    "Code": "ADT",
                    "Quantity": "1"
                  }
                
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "SpecialReqDetails": {
        "AddRemark": {
          "RemarkInfo": {
            "FOP_Remark": [
              {
                "Type": "CHECK"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "SpecialService": {
          "SpecialServiceInfo": {
            "SecureFlight": [
              {
                "SegmentNumber": "A",
                "PersonName": {
                  "DateOfBirth": "2001-01-14",
                  "Gender": "M",
                  "NameNumber": "1.1",
                  "GivenName": "ABC",
                  "Surname": "DEF"
                },
                "VendorPrefs": {
                  "Airline": {
                    "Hosted": true
                  }
                }
              }
             
            ],
            "Service": [
              {
                "SSR_Code": "OTHS",
                "Text": "CC JOHN DOE"
              }
             
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "PostProcessing": {
        "EndTransaction": {
          "Source": {
            "ReceivedFrom": "API TEST"
          }
        },
        "RedisplayReservation": {},
        "PricingInterval": {
          "waitInterval": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }

the response is:
{
    "errorCode": "ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
    "message": "Unable to process the stateless transaction. Please retry.",
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "type": "Application",
    "timeStamp": "2024-10-04T05:59:50Z"
}


What am I missing here? Or is this something to do with my account?
